# NSNotificationCenter for presenting multiple modals?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have an app delegate, whose default view should be preceeded by a modal view controller, and sometimes by two modal view controllers. So in the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I'm checking if there is need for, and in that case displays, the first modal view controller.

Upon dismissing the first modal view controller (using `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`), I may want to display the second modal view controller. This is known by the app delegate as well.

So my solution was to use `NSNotificationCenter` to tell the app delegate that the first modal view controller now have been dismissed. When that happens, the second modal view controller can be displayed by the app delegate, if it is needed.

It works fine, but is there a cleaner solution? I think `NSNotificationCenter` is really ugly stuff.

---

**Note on displaying multiple modal view controllers at once**

I did try to display the first AND the second modal view controller inside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but I never got it working. Here's what I tried:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [tabBarController presentModalViewController:pinViewController animated:NO];

    if([self needsActivation]) {
        [tabBarController presentModalViewController:activationViewController
                          animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The above code works with the following correction:

```
    if([self needsActivation]) {
        [pinViewController presentModalViewController:activationViewController
                           animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, there was no need for `NSNotificationCenter`, as I thought. I had tried to display multiple modal view controllers, but I'd made an error.

When displaying the modal view controller B from the modal view controller A, it works fine. I had tried presenting modal view controller A and B from a parent view controller.

So when presenting modal view controllers in a hierarchy instead, there is no need for `NSNotificationCenter`. The view controllers are dismissing themselves, animations works and I'm a step further towards bending the UIKit to my will.

I've edited the code in my question, which now works fine.